# Visual studio 2017 | Unable to get client context

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to connect to sharepoint online site using console application in VS 2017 but everytime it returns 400 bad request.

Same code works as expected in VS 2013

```
   System.Security.SecureString securestring = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char ch in password)
            securestring.AppendChar(ch);
        SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securestring);

            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = creds;
                Web web = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;

                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow up the steps below.

1.Create a new Console App project(ConsoleApp1) in Visual Studio 2017.

2.Install Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM library using NuGet below.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM -Version 16.1.8412.1200
```

3.Add the following code into Program.cs file.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";
            var userName = "lz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            var password = "xxx";


            System.Security.SecureString securestring = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char ch in password)
                securestring.AppendChar(ch);
            SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securestring);

            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = creds;
                Web web = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;

                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4.Modify the "siteUrl", "userName" and "password" in the code, and run it using F5.